# Make this query more efficent it's taking over 15 mins to run

Tags: sql

```
Use ANALYTICS

Go

SELECT NWPFFS AS HUB,
       LCRGN AS REG,
       LCDST AS DIST,
       ILLCN AS LOC,
       LCNAM AS [LOC NAME],
       LXLTYP AS LOCTYPE, 
       IXPBSN AS B, 
       IXPGRP AS G, 
       IXPDPT AS D,
       ITITMN AS ITEM,
       ITMFGN AS MFG#,
       ITDSC1 AS DESC1,
       ITDSC2 AS DESC2, 
       ITINVM AS [STK CD], 
       ITVND AS VEND#,
       ITHGT AS VENDOR,
       ILOHNQ AS [ON HAND],
       ILCMTP AS COMPURCH,
       ILCMTC AS COMSALE,
       ILYSLQ AS [SLS YTD QTY],
       ILLYSQ AS [SLS LY QTY], 
       ILINVV AS [INV VAL]
  FROM (dbo.Item_Location_Master 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Item_Master 
    ON ILITMN=ITITMN)
 INNER JOIN dbo.Location_Master 
    ON ILLCN = LCLCN
 WHERE ((LXLTYP='R') OR (LXLTYP='T'))
   AND ((ITBOMT <> 'T') AND (ITBOMT <> 'S')) 
   AND ((ILOHNQ<>0) OR (ILCMTP<>0)) 
   AND (IXPBSN <> 9) 
   AND ((ILITMN<>21542) OR (ILITMN<>21750))
   AND (NWPFFS<>9900)
```

Comment: nice column names... why? why....?

Comment: exactly my thought after 1 second

Comment: Those columns look like something that came out of an SAP system :-)

Comment: usually I'm all like "don't rename the column names before sending it back, just give me the raw data!" and then there's this....

Comment: Can you say "please"?  What have you tried so far?  If you systematically remove your `WHERE` clauses one at a time, which ones have the most impact?  How are your tables indexed?  What happens when you run this through an execution path analyzer?  Are there specific steps in the execution path which move more records than needed or consume high CPU?

Comment: Ahaha indeed... Looks like the [infinite monkey theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) replaced Shakespeare with SQL

Comment: "It optimizes the query or else it gets the hose again."

Comment: I think `AND ((ILITMN<>21542) OR (ILITMN<>21750))` should be `AND ((ILITMN<>21542) AND (ILITMN<>21750))`

Comment: @Drackir, could also get rid of those ugly parens - `AND ILITMN<>21542 AND ILITMN<>21750`

Comment: Could you imagine the data dictionary for this?  Or wait there probably is no data dictionary is there?

Comment: Me: Send me the spec boss! Boss: There is no spec!

Comment: `LCRGN AS SUNSHINE, LCDST AS RAINBOWS, ILLCN AS PONIES,`

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do is provide indexes on LXLTYP and some of your other fields.
How about giving us more information like your table's current indexes, etc? Those column names are really confusing.

Here's a good article on indexes on SQLTeam.com: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-indexes-the-basics

Answer (score 0):

Check your table indexing, if you don't have any indexes, now would be a good time to learn about them.

Answer (score 0):

The only advice I can offer is to make sure you have needed indexes and possibly look at creating a persisted denormalized version of the two tables.

You could do this in SQL Server with either an Indexed view or a table that you load with the required data.

If you provide more information (execution plan would be a good place to start) we can offer more detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the query plan or indexes on the tables, I can't really do any sort of concrete diagnosis.  However, here are a few suggestions:

- Examine the query plan to see what operations are taking the time.  If the plan is wrong, there will probably be one operation taking 99% of the time.
- Convert the ORs into [s-argable](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_miller/archive/2008/08/29/what-is-a-sarg-exactly-training-classes-and-knowledge-retention.aspx) clauses.  See if this changes the query plan.
- Put indexes on the columns used in the joins.  See if this changes the query plan.
- Check that the statistics on the tables are up to date.  Although this shouldn't really happen on SQL Server, if the statistics get out of date then the optimiser can choose a sub-optimal plan.